# Accessing managed server host name and port from webapp

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, jndi, jmx, weblogic12c

I am working on web application which will be deployed in Weblogic. In this application I need to access the port and host of the managed server. After searching a bit found that JMX with JNDI can help in getting the server details but not sure if host and port details can be accessed in this way, could not find much help in online docs available. Can someone please help me figuring out this?

Comment: what do you mean by accessing..? are you trying to retrieving the host and port...? And how many nodes you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    //Get ServerConfiguration
    ctx = new InitialContext();
    MBeanServer mBeanServer = (MBeanServer) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jmx/runtime");
    ObjectName ServerConfiguration = (ObjectName) mBeanServer
            .getAttribute(new ObjectName(RuntimeServiceMBean.OBJECT_NAME), "ServerConfiguration");
    // Get ListenPort 
    port = mBeanServer.getAttribute(ServerConfiguration, "ListenPort").toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is the host name (not the server name) all you have to do is:

`String hostname = InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString();`